# Celery: The module was not found

Tags: python, celery

I am using Open Semantic Search (OSS) and I would like to monitor its processes using the [Flower tool](http://flower.readthedocs.io). The workers that Celery needs should be given as OSS states on [its website](https://www.opensemanticsearch.org/doc/admin/config/queue)

> The workers will do tasks like analysis and indexing of the queued files. The workers are implemented by etl/tasks.py and will be started automatically on boot by the service opensemanticsearch.

This tasks.py file looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#
# Queue tasks for batch processing and parallel processing
#

# Queue handler
from celery import Celery

# ETL connectors
from etl import ETL
from etl_delete import Delete
from etl_file import Connector_File
from etl_web import Connector_Web
from etl_rss import Connector_RSS


verbose = True
quiet = False

app = Celery('etl.tasks')
app.conf.CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 1

etl_delete = Delete()
etl_web = Connector_Web()
etl_rss = Connector_RSS()


#
# Delete document with URI from index
#

@app.task(name='etl.delete')
def delete(uri):
    etl_delete.delete(uri=uri)


#
# Index a file
#

@app.task(name='etl.index_file')
def index_file(filename, wait=0, config=None):

    if wait:
        time.sleep(wait)

    etl_file = Connector_File()

    if config:
        etl_file.config = config

    etl_file.index(filename=filename)

#
# Index file directory
#

@app.task(name='etl.index_filedirectory')
def index_filedirectory(filename):

    from etl_filedirectory import Connector_Filedirectory

    connector_filedirectory = Connector_Filedirectory()

    result = connector_filedirectory.index(filename)

    return result


#
# Index a webpage
#
@app.task(name='etl.index_web')
def index_web(uri, wait=0, downloaded_file=False, downloaded_headers=[]):

    if wait:
        time.sleep(wait)

    result = etl_web.index(uri, downloaded_file=downloaded_file, downloaded_headers=downloaded_headers)

    return result


#
# Index full website
#

@app.task(name='etl.index_web_crawl')
def index_web_crawl(uri, crawler_type="PATH"):

    import etl_web_crawl

    result = etl_web_crawl.index(uri, crawler_type)

    return result


#
# Index webpages from sitemap
#

@app.task(name='etl.index_sitemap')
def index_sitemap(uri):

    from etl_sitemap import Connector_Sitemap

    connector_sitemap = Connector_Sitemap()

    result = connector_sitemap.index(uri)

    return result


#
# Index RSS Feed
#

@app.task(name='etl.index_rss')
def index_rss(uri):

    result = etl_rss.index(uri)

    return result


#
# Enrich with / run plugins
#

@app.task(name='etl.enrich')
def enrich(plugins, uri, wait=0):

    if wait:
        time.sleep(wait)

    etl = ETL()
    etl.read_configfile('/etc/opensemanticsearch/etl')
    etl.read_configfile('/etc/opensemanticsearch/enhancer-rdf')

    etl.config['plugins'] = plugins.split(',')

    filename = uri

    # if exist delete protocoll prefix file://
    if filename.startswith("file://"):
        filename = filename.replace("file://", '', 1)

    parameters = etl.config.copy()

    parameters['id'] = uri
    parameters['filename'] = filename

    parameters, data = etl.process (parameters=parameters, data={})

    return data


#
# Read command line arguments and start
#

#if running (not imported to use its functions), run main function
if __name__ == "__main__":

    from optparse import OptionParser 

    parser = OptionParser("etl-tasks [options]")
    parser.add_option("-q", "--quiet", dest="quiet", action="store_true", default=False, help="Don\'t print status (filenames) while indexing")
    parser.add_option("-v", "--verbose", dest="verbose", action="store_true", default=False, help="Print debug messages")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if options.verbose == False or options.verbose==True:
        verbose = options.verbose
        etl_delete.verbose = options.verbose
        etl_web.verbose = options.verbose
        etl_rss.verbose = options.verbose

    if options.quiet == False or options.quiet==True:
        quiet = options.quiet

    app.worker_main()
```

I read multiple tutorials about Celery and from my understanding, this line should do the job

```
celery -A etl.tasks flower
```

but it doesnt. The result is the statement

> Error: Unable to load celery application. The module etl was not found.

Same for

```
celery -A etl.tasks worker --loglevel=debug
```

so Celery itself seems to be causing the trouble, not flower. I also tried e.g. celery -A etl.index_filedirectory worker --loglevel=debug but with the same result.

What am I missing? Do I have to somehow tell Celery where to find etl.tasks? Online research doesn't really show a similar case, most of the "Module not found" errors seem to occur while importing stuff. So possibly it's a silly question but I couldn't find a solution anywhere. I hope you guys can help me. Unfortunately, I won't be able to respond until Monday though, sorry in advance.

Comment: Is the `tasks.py` module located in `etl` package? I.e. does `etl` contain `__init__.py`?

Comment: Yes, there is an init file, it's empty though. Should it contain some code?

Comment: Nobody's got an idea?

Comment: @starsnpixel I don't see an answer here, and this comment _"Do I have to somehow tell Celery where to find etl.tasks?"_ makes me think we both have a similar incorrect idea-- etl.tasks is not just a name but a path! For me I'm using celery with django, and I called celery from the wrong directory. For my django project I call  `$ celery -A <project> beat -l INFO` where `<project>` is the django project named folder with `settings.py`.

Comment: @xtian thanks for coming back at this after all this time. However, I stopped working with Celery a bit after posting this question without having a solution. Thus, I cannot test your proposition but maybe it helps others with the same issue, thus thanks for posting. :)

Comment: @starsnpixel, Not the worst necro-bump I've experienced on SO. hehe. I read a lot of peeps drop Celery for other task managers. Did you choose a different task manager to use with Python? (or something else altogether?)

Comment: Haha "necro-bump", I like the word! The project for which I wanted to use Celery was cancelled so I left the whole topic behind.

Answer (score 7):

I got same issue, I installed and configured my queue as follows, and it works.

**Install RabbitMQ**

*MacOS*

```
brew install rabbitmq
sudo vim ~/.bash_profile
```

In `bash_profile` add the following line:

`PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin`

Then update `bash_profile`:

`sudo source ~/.bash_profile`

*Linux*

`sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server`

**Configure RabbitMQ**

Launch the queue:

`sudo rabbitmq-server`

In another Terminal, configure the queue:

```
sudo rabbitmqctl add_user myuser mypassword
sudo rabbitmqctl add_vhost myvhost
sudo rabbitmqctl set_user_tags myuser mytag
sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p myvhost myuser ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

**Launch Celery**

I would suggest to go in the folder that contains `task.py` and use the following command:

`celery -A task worker -l info -Q celery --concurrency 5`

Answer (score 7):

Beware that this error means two things:

1. The module is missing
2. The module exists **but cannot be loaded**. If it has errors in it, such as a SyntaxError for instance.

To check that it's not the latter, run:

```
python -c "import <myModuleContainingTasksDotPyFile>"
```

In the context of this question:

```
python -c "import etl"
```

If it crashes, fix this first (Unlike with celery, you'll get a detailed error message).

Answer (score 4):

Try `export PYTHONPATH=<parent directory>` where parent directory is the folder where the `etl` is. Run the Celery worker, and see it if fixes your problem. This is probably one of the most common Celery "issues" (not really Celery, but Python in general). Alternatively, run the Celery worker from that folder.

Comment: This was a very useful suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Solutions above did not work for me.

I had the same issue and my problem was that in main celery.py (that was in SmartCalend folder) I had:

```
app = Celery('proj')
```

but instead I must type there:

```
app = Celery('SmartCalend')
```

where SmartCalend is the actual app name where celery.py belongs (!). not any random word, but precisely app name. Thats nowhere mentioned, only in official docs here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answer for MacOS Catalina:

When you install celery with pip (`pip install celery`), python can `import celery`, but you are not able to launch celery from the terminal because the terminal does not know of the celery executable.

Add celery to the path to fix:

1. `nano ~/.bash_profile`
2. In the file add: `export PATH="/Users/gavinbelson/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"`
3. To save the file in the nano editor: ctrl+o, then enter, then ctrl+x
4. To update the terminal with your change type: `source ~/.bash_profile`
5. Now you should be able to type `celery` in the terminal window

---- Note this is for the default `python` terminal command which runs version 2.7. If you are using `python3` to run python, you would need to change alter the path variable accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to rename project folder "etl.tasks" to "etl_tasks", where is "setting.py" file. Dot fail it.